# Issue trying to convert txt file to fits file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, file-conversion, astropy, fits

I'm new here, and I've been struggling with this for a few days. So I have an txt file with a cds table of data that I need to convert to a fits file in order to open it in a specific program. Based off the *many* help websites I read with examples of code to accomplish this exact thing, the code that I need basically looks something like what I have pasted below, with no need to use open() or close() functions (though I have also tried that). I'm using jupyter notebooks to run this and so far it hasn't once stopped running; I always have to interrupt it and I think it's getting stuck on the read() line. I'll also post the errors I get below. Event though it never really worked, it somehow created and saved a new fits file like I wanted, but there's only 22 rows of data in the table, but the format is kind of off, even though the file provides the correct info for a cds table file. If you have any suggestions, please let me know.

**CODE**:

```
from astropy.table import Table
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.io import ascii

data = ascii.read(r"C:\...", format='cds')
# (comment: At this line I also tried Table.read() instead of ascii.read() as suggested and "ascii.cds" for format)

data.write("new_table.fits", format='fits')
```

**ERRORS**:

```
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\astropy\io\ascii\core.py in _convert_vals(self, cols)
    971                         raise TypeError('converter type does not match column type')
--> 972                     col.data = converter_func(col.str_vals)
    973                     col.type = converter_type

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\astropy\io\ascii\core.py in generic_converter(vals)
    915     def generic_converter(vals):
--> 916         return numpy.array(vals, numpy_type)
    917 

OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-f59c9c65394f> in <module>
      3 from astropy.io import ascii
      4 
----> 5 data = ascii.read(r"C:\....", format='cds')
      6 # Table.read() instead of ascii.read(), the url instead of the file path, and "cds" for format
      7 

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\astropy\io\ascii\ui.py in read(table, guess, **kwargs)
    321         else:
    322             reader = get_reader(**new_kwargs)
--> 323             dat = reader.read(table)
    324             _read_trace.append({'kwargs': copy.deepcopy(new_kwargs),
    325                                 'Reader': reader.__class__,

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\astropy\io\ascii\cds.py in read(self, table)
    325                     return table
    326         else:
--> 327             return super().read(table)

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\astropy\io\ascii\core.py in read(self, table)
   1228             self.meta['table'].update(self.header.table_meta)
   1229 
-> 1230         table = self.outputter(cols, self.meta)
   1231         self.cols = self.header.cols
   1232 

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\astropy\io\ascii\core.py in __call__(self, cols, meta)
   1000         # Sets col.data to numpy array and col.type to io.ascii Type class (e.g.
   1001         # FloatType) for each col.
-> 1002         self._convert_vals(cols)
   1003 
   1004         t_cols = [numpy.ma.MaskedArray(x.data, mask=x.mask)

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\astropy\io\ascii\core.py in _convert_vals(self, cols)
    972                     col.data = converter_func(col.str_vals)
    973                     col.type = converter_type
--> 974                 except (TypeError, ValueError) as err:
    975                     col.converters.pop(0)
    976                     last_err = err

KeyboardInterrupt:
```

Comment: How big is the file?

Answer (score 1):

Two things that come into mind.

One, you might want to check the content of the file for some number value that is longer than the value indicated in `sys.maxsize`. For this one, you could easily set a converter for the particular column like this

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> converters = {'col1': [ascii.convert_numpy(np.int64)]}
>>> ascii.read('file.dat', converters=converters)
```

The other thing for the "stuckness". You could try to read the file in chunk shown in this [doc](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/ascii/read.html#reading-large-tables-in-chunks). e.g:

```
tbls = ascii.read('large_table.csv',
                  format='csv',
                  guess=False,
                  fast_reader={'chunk_size': 100 * 1000000,
                               'chunk_generator': True})

out_tbls = []

# At this point the file is actually read in chunks.
for tbl in tbls:
    bright = tbl['Vmag'] < 8.0
    if np.count_nonzero(bright):
        out_tbls.append(tbl[bright])
```

Comment: Thanks you, that's very helpful. For now I will trim down the data so at least I can get the program working, but I'll try this. I should have been more clear though, my main concern with this isn't the overflow, but the fact that the program just runs continuously. I always have to stop/interrupt the kernel, and when I do, I get the output that I posted (below "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:"). This happens even when I trim the file and thus do not have the overflow issue. Does anyone have any idea why it does this?

Comment: Hi, without the input file, I probably can only guess what was happen. But, maybe you could try to read with input file that contains only 1-2 rows? from there, if nothing happens (as in, you don't need to stop/interrupt the kernel), then, I guess you could check for the memory usage of the script. It probably become sluggish because python try to claim some memory space

Comment: Yep, I did exactly that; I figured I can deal with the overflow, but the other thing must be a deeper issue. Even having only about 6 rows in the table, the longest I waited before interrupting was probably 10-15 minutes, and the result is the same as above. The thing is, as shown above, there's an exception at the bottom that I don't understand but no error I think? It mostly shows the output of the code that was running when I stopped it. With so little data in the file, is it even possible that I just didn't let it run long enough?

Comment: Is the exception you're referring is this one (`except (TypeError, ValueError) as err:`)? If yes, then I guess you could ignore it for now. Hmm, have you checked the memory usage when you running the script? probably, looking at task manager should be suffice enough.. Reason why, is because the default process for reading ASCII tables is not memory efficient and may temporarily require much more memory than the size of the file (up to a factor of 5 to 10). In cases where the temporary memory requirement exceeds available memory this can cause significant slowdown when disk cache gets used .